# Randomly delete rows due to a variable in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, random

In my `data` below, I wonder how to delete all rows with a given value of `outcome` (say `"A"`) from `n` (say `1`) ***randomly*** selected `study`ies?

The only condition is that we want to select only from studies that have used more than one value of `outcome` (e.g., `study==1` and `study==2` each of which has both `outcome == "A"` and `outcome == "B"`).

For example, below let's say the given value of `outcome` is `"A"`. Then, for a given `n` (say `n = 1`), we delete all rows with with `outcome == "A"` from `n = 1` randomly selected `study` from `study==1` or `study==2`.

Is this possible in `R`?

```
m =
  "
  study group outcome 
1     1     1       A   
2     1     1       B    
3     1     2       A 
4     1     2       B 
5     2     1       A   
6     2     1       B    
7     2     2       A 
8     2     2       B
9     3     1       B
10     4     1       B  
"  
data <- read.table(text=m,h=T)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

n = 1
studies_to_remove = sample(unique(data$study), size = n)
outcome_to_remove = "A"

data %>%
  filter(
    !(
      study %in% studies_to_remove &
        outcome %in% outcome_to_remove
    )
  )
 
#    study group outcome
# 2      1     1       B
# 4      1     2       B
# 5      2     1       A
# 6      2     1       B
# 7      2     2       A
# 8      2     2       B
# 9      3     1       B
# 10     4     1       B
```

Comment: I also actually had a similar question [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69679211/7223434), would you mind taking a look? Thanks.